# jQuery combine id, class and multiple attribute selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After read [jQuery API doc Selectors page](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) I had no idea how to combine in one statement this three types of selector.

- [ID Selector ("#id")](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
- [Class Selector (".class")](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)
- [Multiple Attribute Selector [name=”value”][name2=”value2″]](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Now I think this could be a template to use them all at same time

**`$("#myUniqueId.class1.class2.nClass[attribute1='value1'][nAttribute='nValue']")`**

This could be an example of how to select a div element:

```
<html>
  <div id="left-sidebar" data-is-here-when="md lg" class="left-sidebar js-pinned-left-sidebar ps-relative">
<html>
<script>
  jQuery("#left-sidebar.left-sidebar.js-pinned-left-sidebar[data-is-here-when='md lg']")
</script>
```

Thanks all for the answers and comments

Comment: `li.is-selected[id='wmd-help-button']` would be possible. `li[.is-selected]` would just look for an element that has an attribute with the _name_ `.is-selected`.

Comment: What exactly is the element you're trying to select? The second selector isn't valid because you can't put a class selector in to an attribute selector. The first one works, but `*=` is used to select by an attribute containing the provided value, so not the same as a standard class selector. It's possible you just need `li#wmd-help-button.is-selected`, but without seeing the HTML this is a guess.

Comment: Why are you using the attribute selector at all? Why not `li#wmd-help-button.is-selected` ?

Comment: what about `$('li#wmd-help-button.is-selected')`

Comment: **Try this -->** `jQuery('li.is-selected[id="wmd-help-button"]').text();`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need

```
$("li.is-selected#wmd-help-button")
```

Comment: Thanks @jafar my doubt was how to add to your correct answer another attribute filter by selector like: ```$("li#wmd-help-button.is-selected"[attrName='attrValue']) ```

Comment: use like this: $("li#wmd-help-button.is-selected[attrName=attrValue]")

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should only have one item with given id on a page, so start with `#wmd-help-button`.

If that button may be selected and you need to differentiate on that, do `#wmd-help-button.is-selected`.

Answer (score -2):

**Try this -->**

`jQuery('li.is-selected[id="wmd-help-button"]').text();`

Comment: Why `[id="wmd-help-button"]` instead of `#wmd-help-button` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Paras, now I know id is special but your try works fine with another attributes

Comment: Now i think your try is better in this way ```jQuery("li#wmd-help-button.is-selected").text();```